# dma for FPGA based PCI IO card

Tags: io, fpga, dma, pci

I have mesa electronics 5i20 PCI card. An application is provided which takes in data on PC and send it to FPGA on card and similarly it reads data back from FPGA on card to PC.

PCI supports 33MHz data transfer. Using simple for loop, I can send and receive data to and from FPGA respectively. But how I can use DMA concept so that I may read a file data and send few chunks of data directly to card via PCI.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You don't do DMA with PCI, you must bus master from the IO card, so you put your data in system memory, tell the IO card where to read data from and *it* requests the data from the PCI controller, which then gets it from the memory and puts it on the PCI bus for your IO card to read.

Comment: Kindly can you give example reference so things become easier for me.

Comment: What PCI core are you using in your FPGA - usually the user-manual for that will give examples.